# Multikey index: order of array elements in query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm experiencing some strange behavior I cannot understand.
Given collection with documents of following 'schema':

```
{
 tag : ["t:someTag", "A", "B", "C"]
 msg : "some message"
 timestamp : ISODate(...)
 someIntField: 1
}
```

*tag* in an array starting with element "t:something" and followed by arbitrary number of string tags.
Collection stats:

```
db.perf_multikey.stats()
{
        "ns" : "test.perf_multikey",
        "count" : 36239306,
        "size" : 22124848112,
        "avgObjSize" : 610,
        "storageSize" : 24330923904,
        "numExtents" : 32,
        "nindexes" : 4,
        "lastExtentSize" : 2146426864,
        "paddingFactor" : 1,
        "systemFlags" : 1,
        "userFlags" : 1,
        "totalIndexSize" : 17494579648,
        "indexSizes" : {
                "_id_" : 1177303120,
                "tag_1" : 12851094032,
                "timestamp_1" : 1800706768,
                "level_1" : 1665475728
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

I'm executing following query:

```
db.perf_multikey.find({tag: {$all:["t:a", "J"]}})
```

As expected it hits the index and returns couple of rows:

```
db.perf_multikey.find({tag: {$all:["t:a", "J"]}}).explain()
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor tag_1",
        "isMultiKey" : true,
        "n" : 6,
        "nscannedObjects" : 10,
        "nscanned" : 10,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 10,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 22,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 1,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 7,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "tag" : [
                        [
                                "t:a",
                                "t:a"
                        ]
                ]
        },
        "server" : "somefancyserver:27017",
        "filterSet" : false
}
```

But the query that differs only in order of elements in tag array

```
db.perf_multikey.find({tag: {$all:["J","t:a"]}})
```

Doesn't seem to be using index

```
db.perf_multikey.find({tag: {$all:["J","t:a"]}}).explain()
{
        "cursor" : "Complex Plan",
        "n" : 6,
        "nscannedObjects" : 0,
        "nscanned" : 7866684,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 7827833,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 15694517,
        "nYields" : 139716,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 118102,
        "server" : "samefancyserver:27017",
        "filterSet" : false
}
```

I'm using MongoDB 2.6.9
Seeing the aforementioned results I'm confused how MongoDB multikey indexing works. Why the query using an array is so order dependent?

**EDIT:**

After upgrading to MongoDB 3.0.2, I've regenerated dataset (of size big enough so that index won't fit in RAM) and rerun the tests.
Unfortunately I still experience the same results (please mind that *tag* field is following some kind of 'schema' - first element of array is arbitrary string followed by some permutation of tags - from finite universe of values, say "A" - "J").

Those are my results:

Lightning fast:

```
> db.perf_multikey.find({tag : {$all : ["a", "J"]}}).explain()
{
        "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "test.perf_multikey",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {
                        "$and" : [
                                {
                                        "tag" : {
                                                "$eq" : "a"
                                        }
                                },
                                {
                                        "tag" : {
                                                "$eq" : "J"
                                        }
                                }
                        ]
                },
                "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "FETCH",
                                "filter" : {
                                        "tag" : {
                                                "$eq" : "J"
                                        }
                                },
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                        "keyPattern" : {
                                                "tag" : 1
                                        },
                                        "indexName" : "tag_1",
                                        "isMultiKey" : true,
                                        "direction" : "forward",
                                        "indexBounds" : {
                                                "tag" : [
                                                        "[\"a\", \"a\"]"
                                                ]
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : [
                        {
                                "stage" : "FETCH",
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
                                        "inputStage" : {
                                                "stage" : "AND_SORTED",
                                                "inputStages" : [
                                                        {
                                                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                                                "keyPattern" : {
                                                                        "tag" : 1
                                                                },
                                                                "indexName" : "tag_1",
                                                                "isMultiKey" : true,
                                                                "direction" : "forward",
                                                                "indexBounds" : {
                                                                        "tag" : [
                                                                                "[\"a\", \"a\"]"
                                                                        ]
                                                                }
                                                        },
                                                        {
                                                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                                                "keyPattern" : {
                                                                        "tag" : 1
                                                                },
                                                                "indexName" : "tag_1",
                                                                "isMultiKey" : true,
                                                                "direction" : "forward",
                                                                "indexBounds" : {
                                                                        "tag" : [
                                                                                "[\"J\", \"J\"]"
                                                                        ]
                                                                }
                                                        }
                                                ]
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                ]
        },
        "serverInfo" : {
                "host" : "fancyhost",
                "port" : 27017,
                "version" : "3.0.2",
                "gitVersion" : "6201872043ecbbc0a4cc169b5482dcf385fc464f"
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Slow one:

```
> db.perf_multikey.find({tag : {$all : ["J", "a"]}}).explain()
{
        "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "test.perf_multikey",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {
                        "$and" : [
                                {
                                        "tag" : {
                                                "$eq" : "J"
                                        }
                                },
                                {
                                        "tag" : {
                                                "$eq" : "a"
                                        }
                                }
                        ]
                },
                "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "AND_SORTED",
                                        "inputStages" : [
                                                {
                                                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                                        "keyPattern" : {
                                                                "tag" : 1
                                                        },
                                                        "indexName" : "tag_1",
                                                        "isMultiKey" : true,
                                                        "direction" : "forward",
                                                        "indexBounds" : {
                                                                "tag" : [
                                                                        "[\"J\", \"J\"]"
                                                                ]
                                                        }
                                                },
                                                {
                                                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                                        "keyPattern" : {
                                                                "tag" : 1
                                                        },
                                                        "indexName" : "tag_1",
                                                        "isMultiKey" : true,
                                                        "direction" : "forward",
                                                        "indexBounds" : {
                                                                "tag" : [
                                                                        "[\"a\", \"a\"]"
                                                                ]
                                                        }
                                                }
                                        ]
                                }
                        }
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : [
                        {
                                "stage" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                                        "filter" : {
                                                "tag" : {
                                                        "$eq" : "a"
                                                }
                                        },
                                        "inputStage" : {
                                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                                "keyPattern" : {
                                                        "tag" : 1
                                                },
                                                "indexName" : "tag_1",
                                                "isMultiKey" : true,
                                                "direction" : "forward",
                                                "indexBounds" : {
                                                        "tag" : [
                                                                "[\"J\", \"J\"]"
                                                        ]
                                                }
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                ]
        },
        "serverInfo" : {
                "host" : "fancyhost",
                "port" : 27017,
                "version" : "3.0.2",
                "gitVersion" : "6201872043ecbbc0a4cc169b5482dcf385fc464f"
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

I though that http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/#performance may be the answer.

After all, query via ["random string", "A"] uses "random string" to narrow the potential result set to really small size, thus easy to scan (? or further traverse).
On the other hand query via ["A", "random string"] should be slow as "A" will return huge set for further scanning... but query ["A", "random not existing string"] is lightning fast... and that confuses me.

Comment: It is not designed to matter: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/#use-all-to-match-values hmm will need to investigate

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend upgrading. I tested this on both 2.6.1 and 3.0.0 and I do not get this behaviour.

For example, here is 2.6.1:

```
> db.t.find({tags:{$all:['t', 'tags']}}).explain()
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor tags_1",
        "isMultiKey" : true,
        "n" : 1,
        "nscannedObjects" : 1,
        "nscanned" : 1,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 3,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 7,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "tags" : [
                        [
                                "t",
                                "t"
                        ]
                ]
        },
        "server" : "ubuntu:27017",
        "filterSet" : false
}
> db.t.find({tags:{$all:['t', 'tags']}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5549f186450548aed9ad4273"), "tags" : [ "tags", "t" ] }
```

And even with a non-existant value first:

```
> db.t.find({tags:{$all:['f', 'tags']}}).explain()
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor tags_1",
        "isMultiKey" : true,
        "n" : 0,
        "nscannedObjects" : 0,
        "nscanned" : 0,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 0,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 0,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 0,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "tags" : [
                        [
                                "f",
                                "f"
                        ]
                ]
        },
        "server" : "ubuntu:27017",
        "filterSet" : false
}
```

And on 3.0.0:

```
> db.t.find({tags:{$all:['g','t']}}).explain()
{
        "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "test.t",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {
                        "$and" : [
                                {
                                        "tags" : {
                                                "$eq" : "g"
                                        }
                                },
                                {
                                        "tags" : {
                                                "$eq" : "t"
                                        }
                                }
                        ]
                },
                "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "FETCH",
                                "filter" : {
                                        "tags" : {
                                                "$eq" : "t"
                                        }
                                },
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                        "keyPattern" : {
                                                "tags" : 1
                                        },
                                        "indexName" : "tags_1",
                                        "isMultiKey" : true,
                                        "direction" : "forward",
                                        "indexBounds" : {
                                                "tags" : [
                                                        "[\"g\", \"g\"]"
                                                ]
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : [
                        {
                                "stage" : "FETCH",
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
                                        "inputStage" : {
                                                "stage" : "AND_SORTED",
                                                "inputStages" : [
                                                        {
                                                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                                                "keyPattern" : {
                                                                        "tags" : 1
                                                                },
                                                                "indexName" : "tags_1",
                                                                "isMultiKey" : true,
                                                                "direction" : "forward",
                                                                "indexBounds" : {
                                                                        "tags" : [
                                                                                "[\"g\", \"g\"]"
                                                                        ]
                                                                }
                                                        },
                                                        {
                                                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                                                "keyPattern" : {
                                                                        "tags" : 1
                                                                },
                                                                "indexName" : "tags_1",
                                                                "isMultiKey" : true,
                                                                "direction" : "forward",
                                                                "indexBounds" : {
                                                                        "tags" : [
                                                                                "[\"t\", \"t\"]"
                                                                        ]
                                                                }
                                                        }
                                                ]
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                ]
        },
        "serverInfo" : {
                "host" : "ip-172-30-0-35",
                "port" : 27017,
                "version" : "3.0.0",
                "gitVersion" : "a841fd6394365954886924a35076691b4d149168"
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Granted I did not test on 2.6.9 but I have tested on versions lower and higher and I cannot replicate this behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've upgraded mongo to the 3.0.2 version, please see my edit for new test results.